# Segmentation fault in the constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, segmentation-fault

The program compiles but while running, it prints 'asd12', then 'asd45' and then 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)'. It does not print 'asd67'. Can anybody help me regarding this?

```
struct node{
        int a[3];
        int b;
        int c;
        node* parent;
        node(){
            b=0;
            parent=NULL;
        }
    };



     int main(){
            node* x;
            node* y;
            cout << "asd12"<< endl;
            x->a[0]=1;x->a[1]=1;x->a[2]=1;
            cout << "asd45"<< endl;
            y->a[0]=1;y->a[1]=1;y->a[2]=1;
            cout << "asd67"<< endl;
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Which compiler allowed you to even compile this?

Comment: sorry ..i copied it wrong .. i have updated the int main() code and the problem persists.

Comment: You are not allocating any memory for `x` and `y`. But still trying to use them?

Comment: You are invoking undefined behaviour by using uninitialized pointers. `x` and `y` must be allocated before you can access them. Either that or use `node x, y` instead of `node*`.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared x and y to be pointers to objects of struct node, but you didn't create the objects.
The simplest solution would be to change your declarations from

```
node* x;
node* y;
```

to:

```
node x;
node y;
```

which would create automatic node vars, and would allow you to access the array elements like so:

```
x.a[0] = 1;
```

You could alternatively create dynamic vars using

```
node* x = new node;
node* y = new node;
// access vars using pointer syntax
x->a[0] = 1;
// when finished with x and y, delete the created objects
delete x;
delete y;
```